# Visual Studio Web.Config Transform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config, web.config-transform

We have our web.configs transformed nicely.

However, to one of them only, we need to add all of this to the web.config.

Not sure how to add a whole XML node.

```
system.webServer
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect To HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to add XML into a XML file. You should write your own configuration section. This is a straight forward article on msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xdt:Transform="Insert"` on the `<rewrite>` node inside the target transform config file